# How do certain commands change the tabbed autocomplete criteria?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Suppose I am in a directory like this:

> :mydirectory$ ls

```
foo.txt
```

That only file. If I type a command like `cat` and then I tab to autocomplete (assume the ‸ character is actually the caret position and not a character for this purpose)...

> :mydirectory$ cat ‸

changes to (again: the ‸ here is not a character but the caret)...

> :mydirectory$ cat foo.txt ‸

But it is not the same for a command like this:

> :mydirectory$ tar ‸

When tabbing I see the options to autocomplete:

```
A c d r t u x
```

And when writing something like:

> :mydirectory$ tar -zxvf ‸

Then nothing is autocompleted.

**My question** is: how do many commands change the autocomplete rules in bash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commands don't change the autocomplete rules. The autocomplete rules are defined for the shell using scripts and functions and loaded when the shell is started. I am going to use `bash` as an example since I am familiar with that more than the other shells.

The rules for autocomplete in `bash` are defined in the script in `/etc/bash_completion` and supplemented by further scripts in `/etc/bash_completion.d/` directory. These rules are sourced into `bash` when you login.

`bash` has a `complete` command that lets you easily define rules for completion. To see all the rules already defined, you can run `complete -p`.

Now, most distros will already define these rules for you. So, when you type `tar <TAB>`, there is already a rule defined by your distro to show file which match the pattern `*.tar*` and the options of the `tar` command as autocomplete suggestions. This is why when you type `tar`, it gives you the options `A c d r t u x`, but for `tar -zvxf`, it does not since there can be no further options after that. Now, if you out a `.tar.gz` file in that directory, it will suggest that as an autocomplete option since the next thing after the `f` option is a tar file.

The default `/etc/bash_completion` doesn't provide options as suggestions and doesn't filter the file types. In that case, you will also see the `foo.txt` file as a suggestion to `tar`.

You can read about creating your own rules here - https://debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1 and https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2